# Scraping CodeIgniter website with Curl Error "An Error Was Encountered The URI you submitted has disallowed characters."

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl, scrape

I am trying to scrape A website, when I send a curl request, it returns the following:

```
Error :: An Error Was Encountered The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.
```

but when I send the request with Postman or I enter it with my browser it returns normal page.
so now I believe the problem is in my code:

```php
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    return curl_exec($ch);
```

is there any solution; website URL I am trying to get [here](https://kitchen.sayidaty.net/%D8%A3%D9%83%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%AA-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%84%D8%AD%D9%88%D9%85)

Comment: That URL contains characters that are outside the normal ASCII / ANSI range, so a couple things to verify are that A) Your php file is saved as non-ANSI, preferably UTF-8, and B) You haven't mangled the value of `$url` due to encoding issues. For example, try using the escaped version of that url - `$url = 'https://kitchen.sayidaty.net/%D8%A3%D9%83%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%AA-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%84%D8%AD%D9%88%D9%85'`. The escaped URL would also fix the problem of saving the PHP file with an incompatible text encoding, if you were unable to use UTF for some reason.